# Adding profile while deploy

Tags: change-set

I forgot to add profile to changsets. I want to add profile after deploy the change set. How to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply clone the changeset (in the deployment org) you deployed (From the deployment org), add the profiles, send it to destination org and deploy away.